# I don't understand the ethers js v6 error: unsigned transaction cannot define from

Tags: transactions, ethers.js

I'm constructing a `Transaction` class object, then passing it to a `populateTransaction` method, then instantiating the resulting `TransactionLike` object back into a `Transaction` class so that I can get the `unsignedSerialized` property.

[image]

Attempting to pass the `TransactionLike` object to `Transaction.from()` will throw an error below:

[image]

Why does it throw an error stating `unsigned transaction cannot define from`? What does this mean? The `from` property is already autopopulated with my own address after running it through the `populatTransaction` method.